# Ubuntu VPS CPUs sometimes go wild with a process I don't recognize

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage

My VPS sometimes goes wild because of

> /tmp/.X17-unix/.rsync/c/lib/64/tsm --library-path
>   /tmp/.X17-unix/.rsync/c/lib/64/ /tmp/.X17-unix/.rsync/c/tsm64 -t 302
>   -f 1 -s 8 -S 8 -p 0 -d 1

Any idea what it is and what does it do? And more important, how can I make sure it dosn't kill my VPS? Thanks

edit: after killing the pid and restarting the VPS, I'm now seeing 3 pids that kills my CPU with just "./cron" in the command.

I tried cd-ing into .X17-unix to see what's in there but it says the folder does not exist.

After killing the ./cron pid, it is quiet but I guess it will return at some point. The user is root so I can't kill this user, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well... TSM *can* stand for "Tivoli Server Manager", in which case it would be IBM's backup solution just backing up your VPS. Please ask from your VPS provider if that's what they use, if they do not, then it of course can be some blackhatware doing something nasty.

Comment: Running out of `/tmp/.X17-unix/.rsync`?  I know IBM's software is pretty shoddy, but I think even they would do better than that...